# JPanel will only update if JLabels are added in a certain order

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I am currently building a blackjack game, using Java Swing for the front end interface. I have this `updateHandDisplay()` method that updates the cards shown each time a player/dealer draws a new card. For some reason when I had the code like this the new cards would not show up for the human player until the either busted (exceeded 21) or ended their turn. At this point all the drawn cards would display at once. Here is the code:

```
public void updateHandDisplay(Card card, boolean isDealer) {
        // Determine player index to update appropriate hand
        Image cardImage;
        try {
            cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("res/cardRes/" + card.getFilename()).toURI()));
            cardImage = cardImage.getScaledInstance(ui.cardWidth / 5, ui.cardHeight / 5, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon cardImg = new ImageIcon(cardImage);
            JLabel drawnCard = new JLabel();
            drawnCard.setIcon(cardImg);
            drawnCard.setVisible(true);
            if (isDealer) {
                ui.dealerHand.add(drawnCard);
            }
            else {
                ui.userHand.add(drawnCard);
            }**
        }
        catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to find file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I was able to make it work by changing the order so that the `setIcon()` and `setVisible()` methods are called after the `add()` method. I am curious why the order of these operations matters, as it would seem to me that adding a JLabel image that is already set to visible should also automatically adjust the display. Here is the changed section that makes the display update everytime the method is called:

```
if (isDealer) {
            ui.dealerHand.add(drawnCard);
        }
        else {
            ui.userHand.add(drawnCard);
        }
        drawnCard.setIcon(cardImg);
        drawnCard.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: By default components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. By invoking the setIcon() method the component is "revalidate" which calls the layout manager. If this is done before the component has added to the panel, there is nothing to revalidate since the component is not displayed on a visible GUI. Don't keep creating new components. Just create the label with a default icon when you create the GUI. Then you just invoke the `setIcon(...)` method to change the card.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the clarification, the part about the repainting makes sense. I had trouble finding documentation on some of the methods related to painting and validation. As for your suggestion, just to clarify, would you suggest I create and add JLabels to each of my card display spots in the GUI and then just change their icons as needed, or just create a single JLabel in order to not have to create one every time. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You need a separate label for every card spot. They should be created up front.

Comment: @camickr Okay that's what I thought. I had initially resisted doing it that way because it forced me to limit the amount of cards that could be displayed. However, after workshopping other solutions I have gone ahead and shifted my design to pre-make the JLabels as a variable size hand came with other constraints. Thanks again.

Comment: *it forced me to limit the amount of cards that could be displayed* misread the uqestion. You can add cards dynamically to your panel. The trick is to add the card to the panel and then invoke `revalidate()` on the panel, which will then invoke the layout manager. I thought your question was about "flipping" the top card on a deck, in which case you only ever need one label and then you just change the icon to represent the card in the deck. But if you are dealing cards to a player then yes you need to support an unknown number of cards in advance.

Comment: You may want to check out: [Overlay Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) to help you position the cards on your panel.

Comment: @camickr The issue I had with adding cards the the panel dynamically (versus my current solution of adding them to a pre-instantiated JPanel[] was twofold: 1) The cards were not added next to eachother, instead they would be added with some space in between, and then each time another card was added they'd move a bit closer together to make room. I was confused by this since I thought my grid layout (1 R, 5 C) would automatically add them to the slots from left to right. Also, when adding the cards dynamically the "flipping" became more difficult to access the cards already added to flip.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll look into Overlay layout. I'm still confused by the behavior of my gridlayout, because with other gridlayouts I've used, the items would simply be added into the respective grid areas in order, whereas the cards seemed to be added to random areas of the JPanel, more reminiscent of what I'd seen previously with flow layouts.